# concrete examples of finite groups of lie type

Tags: groups-of-lie-type

I was told that there were types of finite groups of lie types, such as $A_l,l\geq 1$, $^2A_l, l \geq 2$, $B_l, l \geq 2$, $^2B_2$ and so on.

My problem is that if there are any concrete examples of groups of various types. I mean, what do they consist of as a group. More precisely, are there any examples of finite groups of types $A_2$ or $^2A_2$?

In addition, what are the differences between $A_l$ and $^2A_l$, or between $B_l$ and $^2B_l$?

Thanks to everyone.

**Added** More precisely, let $k$ be the algebraic closure of the field with 5 elements, and $G = \{ (a_{ij})_{3 \times 3} | a_{ij} \in k, a_{ij}^5 =a_{ij}, 1 \leq i,j \leq 3, \det ((a_{ij})_{3 \times 3}) = 1 \}$. Then is $G$ a finite group of Lie type? If it is, is it of type $A_2$? If it is of type $A_2$, what is the group of type $^2A_2$?

Comment: You know, for example, that groups of type A are just symmetric groups, right? and that groups of type B are like twisted symmetric groups?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you very much for the comment. But what exactly does these **finite** groups look like? Moreover, how does the index on the top left make a difference? Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexYoucis The finite groups of Lie type of type $A$ are not the symmetric groups. They are (depending on precisely what is meant by Lie type) $GL_n$, $SL_n$ or $PGL_n$ over some finite field.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft My bad, I was thinking of Coxeter groups for some reason!

Comment: Carter's book on finite groups of Lie type has a description of all the possible types and descriptions of the groups (at least the simply connected and adjoint ones). I should probably have excluded $GL_n$ as it seems people only allow the fixed points of a Frobenius in a simple algebraic group.

Comment: Ahh, and I am not alone in not being sure what should be meant by the term http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136880/definition-of-finite-group-of-lie-type

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Thank you very much for the comments. In fact I am reading Carters book, and I don't understand how can a Frobenius map permute the simple roots. Would you please tell me how this can happen? I am sorry I am not good at this part, so I wish to make everything more concrete. Thanks very much.

Comment: Your example is indeed a finite group of Lie type of type $A_2$ (it is $SL_3(5)$). I am not sure what you mean by the Frobenius map permuting the simple roots.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: I mean the $2$ on the top left of $^2A_2$. Carter says on page 36 of his book that this denotes the order of the permutation on the simple roots defined by the Frobenius map.